# Question incorrectly added to "drools" feed

Tags: bug, feed

Strange, is this a bug?

"The following item was added to your Stack Exchange "drools" feed."

Mapping composite foreign key to composite primary key where the foreign key is also a primary key

I want to make VM_hostname,datetime and name properties as a composite Key for Disk class . At the same time VM_hostname and datetime of Disk class should refer to VM_hostname and datetime of ...

tagged: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations  Mar 15 at 19:48

[Mapping composite foreign key to composite primary key where the foreign key is also a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819359/mapping-composite-foreign-key-to-composite-primary-key-where-the-foreign-key-is)

A similar thing has happened with another question a few days ago.

Comment: thanks; you're definitely right - we're investigating; updates will be posted to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345506/23354